# Visual Studio C++ 3d plot

Tags: c++, gui, 3d

I want to ask a convenient tool to plot 3D figure by Visual studio C++,such as mesh, surf in matlab, and it must  be integrated in the GUI, like QT or mfc.

I try gnuplot, but it seems cannnot plot in the GUI, so I hope you can help me.

Comment: QT data Visualization